# Most modern framework for developing a Java desktop GUI application

Tags: java, gui

As aside project I plan to create a desktop text editor in the vein of Notepad++(with a few additions I've been pondering).

Im aware that Swing is quite old now, and I haven't really kept up with Java GUI frameworks/libraries since my first year in university(4 years ago).

Would anyone with experience in Java desktop GUIs be able to give me a run down on the more modern/hottest frameworks I could use? I've tried Google but there isn't a lot of discussions that give a definitive pro/con list for frameworks other than AWT, SWT and Swing.

As stated, the application will be in Java(Also open to using Groovy) and for use with Windows 7 and above. I'm not entirely concerned with portability to *nix, if it works just fine on those platforms then ok, if not, I don't intend to make it work on them.

Comment: Anyone have any suggestions??

Answer (score 3):

I recently made some simple apps and I used [JavaFx](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/overview/javafx-overview-2158620.html) for the my experience was that it made a pretty decent display and it wasn't that hard to pick up.  I used the [Intellij](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) ide and with the intellisense it was pretty easy to figure out what widgets were available.

Now I'm not sure if JavaFX is really what would be considered the hot new display framework for java.